# Unix Environment variable is not setting with execute remotely

Tags: linux, shell, unix, putty, plink

I have shell script call test.sh and it contains

```
echo 'welcome'
echo $inf_user
```

when I run this script on unix box output is

> welcome
>
> *myusername*

But when I run this script using plink my output is

> welcome

As you can see it only show welcome and it does not show myusername anymore more

Please help

My plink command is - 
`plink.exe -ssh user@hostname -l user -pw password -m c:/myfile/file.txt hostname`

and 
file.txt contains

```
#!/bin/sh
/folder1/folder2/test.sh
```

Comment: Where does `$inf_user` get set?  That's not a typical environment variable.  If you're looking for your name, try `$USER` in your script (all uppercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you actually login to your server, you also load in environment variables such as `$inf_user`. But when `plink.exe` connects I’m guessing it is not initiating a real SSH session that would load the user profile & related environment variables.

How to solve this depends on setup & install requirements. Not familiar with how `$inf_user` gets set, but perhaps you can do this; I am using my local Mac OS X setup as an example. First login ti the remote Unix/Linux server and type in the following:

```
echo $PATH;
```

The output of that should be something like this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Now in your script on the remote host add this line based on that output to the top of the file:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

That will force the script to use that `PATH` as the `$PATH`.

Also, since `$inf_user` is not a standard Unix/Linux variable it could be that is setup in either the `.bashrc` or `.profile` on the remote system. So you might want to check in there to see of there are any variables that can be copied.

And past all of that, I am not 100% sure on how `plink.exe` works, but that `file.txt` might be better set for `bash` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/folder1/folder2/test.sh
```

I have a funny feeling that when you login you are using the `bash` shell, but this script is using the basic `sh` shell instead which might be causing this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

On most UNIX systems, the variable `$USER` can be used to access the username of the currently logged-in user. The variable `$inf_user` is specific to whatever setup you happen to have.

Also, on an unrelated note, I see that you are specifying the password in the command. You generally should not do that as commands are recorded unencrypted in command history and may be visible to anyone who can run `ps` on the machine. I suggest you run a command which does not include the password but allows the password to be entered via standard input, instead.